# how to map the TFS workspace to local by using Command Line Client

Tags: tfs, cmd

I am trying to map the TFS workspace to local by using the below comment

```
tf workfold /map /login:username,pwd /server:http://servername:8080/tfs /workspace:'$/source/app/TFS_Label' 'C:\TFS_Label'
```

but am getting the error saying

```
An argument error occurred: workfold requires zero, one, or two path arguments.
```

kindly help on this issue.I am new to TFS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not quite passing in the correct arguments to `TF Workfold` Also the `server` parameter is deprecated.

If you're using TFS 2005 / 2008 then you need to use `server`, if your using TFS 2010 or above then you need to use `collection` instead. Having said that `server` will work if you have a single collection in TFS that is called "DefaultCollection" on newer versions of TFS

The syntax is

`tf workfold /map serverfolder localfolder
               [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]
               [/workspace:workspacename]
               [/login:username,[password]]`

So for TFS 2010 or newer your command should look something like this

`tf workfold "$/source/app/TFS_Label" "C:\TFS_Label" /map /login:username,pwd /collection:http://servername:8080/tfs/defaultcollection /workspace:"MyWorkspaceName"`

For older versions of TFS use

`tf workfold "$/source/app/TFS_Label" "C:\TFS_Label" /map /login:username,pwd /server:http://servername:8080/tfs /workspace:"MyWorkspaceName"`

A workspace is the container for the folder mapping so if you have an existing workspace then you can use that. If not then you can create a workspace using the `TF Workspace /new`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer..now am getting error saying An argument error occurred: The workspace 'TFS_Label' could not be found. I gave workspace name as my local machine workspace.i don't understand how workspace keyword working in the TFS.Please help me..

Comment: By default a workspace name is a combination Machine Name and User Name so it would look something like this "MYPC1234;username" you can view your workspace name in Source Control Explorer by clicking on the workspace dropdown at the top of the window